# Only address or entire function is passed when we pass function as an argument?

Tags: javascript

I have been using JavaScript for quite sometime but this question keeps coming back to me every now and then. Consider the following code snippet :

```
function dummyFunc(inputFunc){
    return inputFunc();
}

function getNumber{
    return 100;
}

dummyFunc(getNumber);
```

When am passing `getNumber` - only the address of function gets passed or entire function declaration gets passed to `dummyFunc` ?

If this is answered already please let me know ?

Comment: getNumber function will give sintax error

Comment: Functions are objects are reference values.

Comment: Why are you asking? It doesn't make a difference anyway, as functions are immutable.